# Need a second eye to debugging a query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

This perhaps is a peculiar problem and I do need a second eye. I am running th following query in my PHP script but am having problem finding the errring line in my query. When I echo the $query, I see the output which valid but the query gives and error at the end of the output saying:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''),('1','$GPRMC','040837.002','A','60.15465','N','24.7436','E','0.5',1970,01,01'' at line 1

I am running the following query:

```
query = "INSERT INTO rmc_raw_data
           (device_id, nmea, rmc_time, signal, latitude, north, longitude, east, speed, track_angle, rmc_date, magnetic_variation, west,check_sum) 
         VALUES";
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
  $numlines++;

  $myDay=substr($data[9], 0,2);
  $myMonth=substr($data[9], 2,2);
  $myYear=substr($data[9], 4,2);            

  $rmc_date = convertToNiceDate($myDay, $myMonth, 2000+$myYear);

  $longitude = convertToDegrees($data[6]);
  $latitude  = convertToDegrees($data[4]);

  $query .= "('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$latitude','$data[5]','$longitude','$data[7]','$data[8]',$rmc_date','$data[10]','$data[11]','$data[12]'),";
}

$query = substr($query, 0,-1);

echo $query;
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

The query imports and manipulates data from a text file which has the following sample of data lines which are comma delimited:

```
//input data
1,$GPRMC,080323.460,A,6013.45368,N,02445.28396,E,21.6,134.0,070610,6.9,W,A*2A
1,$GPRMC,080327.000,A,6013.44424,N,02445.31214,E,9.0,135.2,070610,6.9,W,A*1E
1,$GPRMC,132305.000,V,,,,,,,070610,,,N*4B
1,$GPRMC,132320.000,V,,,,,,,070610,,,N*4C
1,$GPRMC,132335.000,V,,,,,,,070610,,,N*48
1,$GPRMC,132350.000,V,,,,,,,070610,,,N*4B
1,$GPRMC,134841.000,V,,,,,,,070610,,,N*46
1,$GPRMC,134856.000,A,6009.32417,N,02444.63687,E,1.7,124.8,070610,6.9,W,A*1A
1,$GPRMC,134911.000,A,6009.32239,N,02444.63356,E,,,070610,,,A*64
1,$GPRMC,134927.000,V,,,,,,,070610,,,N*47
1,$GPRMC,155411.405,V,,,,,,,070610,,,N*49
-------
```

While the query outputed the result to screen as I tested to see, it also gave an error at the following point of the output i.e where it terminated:

```
//output data to be inserted
        ('1','$GPRMC','142346.000','A','60.15675','N','24.74189','E','14.1',1970,01,01','290610','6.9','W'),    ('1','$GPRMC','142349.000','A','60.15656','N','24.74203','E','13.5',1970,01,01','290610','6.9','W'),    ('1','$GPRMC','142402.000','A','60.15565','N','24.74287','E','13.2',1970,01,01','290610','6.9','W'),    ('1','$GPRMC','142411.000','A','60.1551','N','24.74347','E','7.3',1970,01,01','290610','6.9','W'),    ('1','$GPRMC','142414.000','A','60.15507','N','24.74346','E','',1970,01,01','290610','',''),    ('1','$GPRMC','142417.000','A','60.15514','N','24.74358','E','6.4',1970,01,01','290610','6.9','W'),    ('1','$GPRMC','142423.000','A','60.15524','N','24.74371','E','',1970,01,01','290610','',''),    ('1','$GPRMC','142435.000','A','60.15512','N','24.74365','E','',1970,01,01','290610','',''),
('1','$GPRMC','142447.000','V','0','','0','','',1970,01,01','290610','',''),
('1','$GPRMC','142459.000','V','0','','0','','',1970,01,01','290610','',''),
('1','$GPRMC','062917.637','V','0','','0','','',1970,01,01','070610','',''),
('1','$GPRMC','062932.000','V','0','','0','','',1970,01,01','070610','',''),
('1','$GPRMC','063206.392','V','0','','0','','',1970,01,01','070610','',''),
('1','$GPRMC','080238.101','V','0','','0','','',1970,01,01','070610','',''),
('1','$GPRMC','080253.000','V','0','','0','','',1970,01,01','070610','',''),
('1','$GPRMC','080305.000','V','0','','0','','',1970,01,01','070610','',''),
('1','$GPRMC','080308.000','V','0','','0','','',1970,01,01','070610','','')


You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '','070610','6.9','W'),('1','$GPRMC','080327.000','A','60.22407','N','24.7552','E' at line 1
```

I have been working to trace the error but no solution. I had achieved same result with a similar nature of file without qualms. But this is getting me nuts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$rmc_date` is not quoted properly.

Comment: funny how the SO syntax highlighting gave it away... :)

Comment: The more I looked the less I saw. Diminishing returns it seem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

missing quote near "$rmc_date"

Comment: serious! I needed a second eye man. thanks. i correct that  and hopes that is the only issue.